# to convert datetime into date string from 2019-05-02 12:00:00 to 2019-05-02

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl

I am trying to run a query inside a package in sql transformation. tryo to convert the datetime to string where i have the value 2019-05-02 12:00:00 AM to 2019-05-02

```
*
FROM <MyTable>  where datekey ='" + (DT_STR,20,1252)(@[User::NextStartTime]) + "'
```

I tried this but it gives an output as datekey = '12:00:00 AM' but i am looking for '2019-05-02'

Comment: Figured it out. Here is the solution.

where datekey ='" + (DT_WSTR,30)year(@[User::NextStartTime]) + "-" + Right ("0"+(DT_WSTR,30)month(@[User::NextStartTime]),2) + "-" + Right("0"+(DT_WSTR,30)day(@[User::NextStartTime]),2) + "'

Comment: Why not just using `LEFT((DT_WSTR,30)@[User::NextStartTime],10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the following expression:

```
LEFT((DT_WSTR,50)@[User::NextStartTime],10)
```

Output:

> 2019-05-10

Based on the [Cast (SSIS Expression) official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017):

> When a string is cast to a DT_DATE, or vice versa, the locale of the transformation is used. However, the date is in the ISO format of YYYY-MM-DD, regardless of whether the locale preference uses the ISO format.